# Voronoi Diagrams and Toxic Waste Dump Problem

Tags: voronoi-diagram

I am struggling to understand/believe the idea that the center of the largest empty circle or optimal location for a "toxic waste dump" on a Voronoi diagram is on a vertex. 
For example, if I have a Voronoi diagram with sites $A=(1,3), B=(6,4), C= (6,1)$ the Toxic Waste Dump problem tells me that the optimal location for a toxic waste dump would be at the vertex $(3.7, 2.5)$.
What I have read of the Toxic Waste Dump problem is that it tells you the optimal place to put a waste dump so that it is 
 1. furthest from all existing site
 2. not closest to any one particular site.

I understand that it is "fair" to place it on the vertex, but I don't see how that maximizes the distance.
In the example above, why shouldn't the waste dump be placed at $(2.5, 8.5)$?
This point is equidistant from $A$ and $B$ (it lies on their edge) and is further from both $A$ and $B$ than the vertex is.

Any help explaining this would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your initial statement only applies if the Voronoi tiles are all finite.   Otherwise, why not put the dump at somewhere like $(100,10000)$ or even further away?  Usually the problem is stated as the possible location being restricted to the convex hull of the original points, and the optimal point is either at the intersection of Voronoi edges, or where a Voronoi edge meets the convex hull